# Maven: Creating uber jar of dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, uberjar

I have a java project with dependencies `d1` & `d2`. `d1` depends on `d3-1.0` & `d2` depends on `d3-2.0`. Now, I'm facing issues because only one out of `d3-1.0` &  `d3-2.0` gets included in the final libs.

The problem can be evaded by creating uber jars of `d1` & `d2` with their respective dependencies inside them. But, the uber jars of dependencies are not available.

Is there a way where I can create an uber-jar of a dependency(with all of their respective dependencies inside it) while I'm building my project?

Something like below:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>dependency.group.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>d1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <uber-jar>true</uber-jar>                  //Something like mentioning this would create an uber jar of this dependency.
</dependency>
```

Comment: why not simply add the missing dependency in your project ?

Comment: Maven does not like multiple versions of the same artifact (and it typically gives you a lot of problems).  Fix your code so only one of them is needed.

Comment: Why not updating d1 to use d3-2.0 instead of the old version? Using two version of the same lib will lead you to classpath hell.

Comment: @all: There can be multiple problems in increasing versions. There are a huge number of dependencies and they, in turn, have a huge number of dependencies. And when you resolve for one dependency version, it can cause an issue for some other dependency. Also, I don't want to touch unwanted variables because of uncertainty it can cause in production. A world in which a dependency can act as a standalone & doesn't get affected by outside world and vice-versa can be a huge lifesaver.

Comment: @davidxxx both `d1` & `d2` are dependent on diff versions of `d3`. There is no way I can add multiple versions of same `d3` in my pom

Comment: I think you're asking for trouble. Two version of the same lib means two version of classes with identical names. Which one will be loaded? When a class is loaded in the classloader another version of a class with an identical name can't be loaded in the same classloader. So if you don't create a custom classloader able to handle two version of the same lib you're screwed. And creating a working classloader able to do that is not a trivial task

Comment: This is the exact reason for my question. Read it again, I've mentioned that since multiple versions of `d3` cannot work together, how can I make the 2nd level dependency abstract from my project.

Comment: I've read it again. You've wrote that maven prevent you from using two version of the same lib and how you need to create uber jar to bypass this mecanism. By this you're implying that they can work together. What i'm saying is even if you hide your two version of the same lib in two uber jars it won't solve your classloading issue. Either update d1 or d2 to use the same version of d3 or refactor one version of d3 to prevent name colision and compile it. Or maybe i read your post wrongly again?

Comment: Yeah. Maybe you are right. Then, I'll also need to shade apart from creating uber-jar of the dependencies.

Comment: What is d3? Are there some breaking changes between d3-1.0 &  d3-2.0? Maybe you can test if using d3-2.0 is breaking your app?

Comment: Yeah, there are breaking changes involved